# Understand shmat and attachment to the process memory?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, ipc, shared-memory

It is recommended/conventional that the second argument to `shmat(int id , void * addr,int flg)` should be NULL.

But if i want to give it a specific address (`void* addr`), *should that address be from the stack or the heap?*

I mean  do i have to malloc() and then pass that address to shmat or i can just declare void * adrr(or char * addr) and pass it to shmat.

Comment: why do you want to specify it? it looks as if you've just created an artificial problem.

Comment: I  was learning System V IPC and i could not understand the purspose of the second argument if it is always supposed to be NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the diagram below:

[image]

If **addr** is NULL, the system selects the first available address without corrupting the BSS segment. Most probably that will be in the heap. So you don't need to allocate.

If **addr** is from the stack segment of your application, calling *shmat* will corrupt the stack. Most probably that will result in a segmentation fault in your program. shmat will overwrite the variables on the stack, located at addresses lower than the one you gave as parameter.

So if you want to send an address, **you have better chances of not breaking anything** if that address is from the heap. As in the stack's case **you can overwrite data that resides in the heap** and you don't want that. But usually the heap space is filled more "sparsely".

If you really want to not use NULL, you can *allocate some memory on the heap, and give the pointer to the memory that has just been allocated*. Make sure you allocate the right size.

I pasted the documentation related to *shmat*:

> If shmaddr isn't NULL and SHM_RND is specified in shmflg, the attach
>   occurs at the address equal to shmaddr rounded down to the nearest
>   multiple of SHMLBA. Otherwise shmaddr must be a page-aligned address
>   at which the attach occurs

So even if you give a not NULL address for attaching the shared memory segment, it has to be page-aligned. Otherwise it will be rounded down.

Comment: If you give it a heap address, you'll corrupt your heap.  Pass it an address known not to be in use, unless you want it to overlay and destroy what's already there.

Comment: Then isn't the same thing  valid for stack memory ?

Comment: @AndrewHenle. Bug in my answer. Fixed it :)

Comment: @VAndrei:  `shmat()` may require a page-aligned address.  It would be an interesting experiment to overwrite a chunk of heap memory with a forced-address `shmat()` call.  I suspect if you started with a page-aligned chunk of memory from the heap obtained via `valloc()` or `memalign()` that was an exact multiple of the page size, and then called `shmat()` with the address of that block to attach a shared memory segment of exactly the same size (or smaller), you wouldn't see any problems.  At least until after you called `free()` on that memory...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks. I added some more comments to highlight the point.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be either, unless you **want** the attached memory to overlay/destroy what's already there.  You don't need nor want to create any memory - the shmat( ) call does that itself. (By attaching to an already-existing shared memory segment.)

Which is why it's best to just leave it NULL.

Comment: what was bothering me was that there must be some use of the second argument in some case.

Comment: The use is to force the attached memory to be at a specific location.  I've seen it done - even by commercial applications from very well known companies - but all it ever seems to do is cause problems such as limit stack or heap growth.  The only possible seemingly legit use I can think of is if you **know** what's already at that location and **want** to nuke it.